# Why is Gmail API ListThreadResponse get Threads not doing anything?

Tags: java, android, gmail-api

I am trying to start basic and get a list of all threads in my inbox. I only have 14 total to make testing easy. Whenever I use the following:

```
ListLabelsResponse lR = mService.users().labels().list(user).execute();
```

I am able to get the list of labels. But when I try to do the same for threads following the developers tutorial from google: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/list

```
 ListThreadsResponse threadResponse =
                mService.users().threads().list(user).setQ(query).execute();
```

It never ends. Once the above statement is called, the rest of the method in which this statement is in never runs. Nothing happens. I get no error messages. I tested the above statement with and without the .setQ.

Through lots of logging, I narrowed it down to that single ListThreadResponse statement that makes the program seem like its running forever without doing anything. I waited for 5 minutes just to see if it's really slow but still nothing. Does anyone know why this could be happening?

Comment: Looks good. Could you remove the `setQ` and add the following afterwards? `List<Thread> threads = threadsResponse.getThreads(); for (Thread thread : threads) { System.out.println("Thread ID: " + thread.getId()); }`. It should not hang.

Comment: I have tried what you mentioned before and it would never work. I don't understand why I am able to get the labels, but not the threads.

Comment: Are you just using the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels` in your client? That might be what is stopping it from working.

Comment: Where would I find those? Do you mean this?  `private static final String[] SCOPES = { GmailScopes.GMAIL_LABELS };`   That's what I have. I changed it to `private static final String[] SCOPES = { GmailScopes.GMAIL_READONLY, GmailScopes.MAIL_GOOGLE_COM, GmailScopes.GMAIL_MODIFY, GmailScopes.GMAIL_INSERT, GmailScopes.GMAIL_COMPOSE};`  after I read your comment. I tested it with and without the labels. Still not working. Not sure if that is the correct scope you are talking about.

Comment: Yeah. If you check the reference documentation for listing labels and threads, you can see that listing threads require a scope with more permission.

Comment: I tried everything you mentioned and read the documentation and did exactly what it specified regarding scopes but it still doesn't want to work. It just hangs.

Comment: I see :) Your `refresh token` is probably not out of date, so the token with the old scopes still work. Make sure you get a new one.

Comment: Sorry. I haven't disappeared. Got really sick. I attempted to do what you mentioned by removing access to my app from Googles "Connected Apps and Services". I wasn't able to find out how to reset the refresh token.Now I ran into the problem of reauthorizing my app to use my google account. I did this initially when I created the application but removed this piece of code when I changed it. Now I have to find exactly when I did this. Will get back to you as soon as I figure this out.

Comment: THANK YOU!. I was able to run old code I had from Github and was able to reset the token and add the scopes I forgot to. Now I am able to get the labels and thread ID's. Thank you so much for your help. I learned quite a lot more about Google API's researching your comments. Could you make an official answer so I can give you credit and mark it as correct?

Comment: Great! :) Added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the documentation for [listing labels](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/list#auth) you will see that the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels` is enough. This will not suffice for listing threads however, which requires a [broader scope](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/list#auth).

If you use the appropriate scopes, and do the authorization step again, you will get `tokens` that will work.